# Create or reuse intermediate SQL table from vb.net? Sorting on a computed field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a vb.net windows forms app where I display records from and SQL table, sorted on 3 fields.  Now I need to also include a sort on a field that needs calculation.  It's not a huge table - about 600 records - and the operation will take place just a few times a day.

My plan is to select the records into an intermediate table,  compute the extra field for each record, and then  select from this intermediate table, using sql to do the sorting including this new computed field.

Do you think it's better to 
a) create this intermediate table each time, then delete the whole thing when done
or 
b) have an empty table in the database that I fill and empty each time.

Any critiques of this plan also welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have already the data on the client side (the 600 records) probably there is no need to go again on the database. You could work on the client side objects like DataTable or use some kind of LINQ expression on the same DataTable

Comment: There are many things you can do: 1-create stored proc that does calculation and returns Dataset. 2-Select records from UI on "as needed" basis and do all calculations on the client. Store data in ADO.NET objects or your custom structures. 3-Do calculations on Client and then store timestamped data on server. -- Surely there are more. This is just too broad

Comment: Thanks! datatable idea worked very well for this. I usually use custom structures, but I wanted the sorting.  Note for people who want to sort multiple columns with datatables:  use datatable.defaultview.sort=(columnlist), and then .defaultview.totable to get the sorted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a relativley straightforward computation, then an intermediate table may not be required. You could just create a view or stored procedure to do it all in one go. Could you give us the details of the calculation?

Comment: It's a complicated calculation that I need to do in VB using all sorts of user data and context.

Comment: In that case, you can select the original dtaa into a datatable, add a column, and then update the column based upon your calculation.

Comment: Thank you - that was perfect!  I will probably use that method often now.  So I wonder if I should edit my original question since it is irrelevant for this problem now, and no one answered that?